# How can we override liferay module in liferay7?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-6.2, liferay-dxp

I am very new to liferay 7 ,actually we are migrating liferay 6.2 to liferay-7 ,in the 6.2 we are using ext to override the action class but in the liferay-7 I am getting some cofusion,could you please help me out.

**The main theme of my ext is :** whenever a new role getting created in an organization from the control panel, we need to store the role information and organization information in our custom table for that we have overriden EditRoleAction.java in **LR6.2** so same thing we are trying to achieve in LR7.

**Action class in Liferay 6.2 :**

**Portal path :**
D:\Liferay6.2workspace\portal\portal-impl\src\com\liferay\portlet\rolesadmin\action\EditRoleAction.java

**Ext Path:**
CutomRoles-ext/docroot/WEB-INF/ext-impl/src/com/liferay/portlet/rolesadmin/action/EditRoleAction.java

**Action class in Liferay 7.0GA4 :**

D:\Liferay7GA4\portal\modules\apps\foundation\roles\roles-admin-web\src\main\java\com\liferay\roles\admin\web\internal\portlet***RolesAdminPortlet.java***

Comment: we're here to "help out", however you only describe some files, but not what you actually want to achieve. What are you doing in the overridden action - or are you adding a new action? Please describe in code- as well as in business terms (don't comment with those details, rather edit your question)

Comment: Hello @OlafKock could you please check the updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really sounds like overriding the Action is not the right place to go. Look up [ServiceWrappers](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/customizing-liferay-services-service-wrappers) - these will run on the business layer, and you can add additional code to (from memory) `RoleLocalService.addRole(...)` and other related methods.

Ext was never necessary for this purpose and shouldn't have been used in the first place. In fact, with the use of ext you deliberately make maintenance and upgrades a lot harder than when you go the regular plugin route. And with Liferay 7 and DXP the use of ext should be the extremely rare absolute exception to the rule. In fact, it's just now being reintroduced after being absent so far (because in a few rare exceptional cases it's still the only way). However, it's safe to assume that you don't need it.

Now that the description in the comments to this answer goes much further than the description in the question: You might need some portlet-level customizations as well. For this: Identify where the portlet is currently implemented (e.g. identify the module) and override its actions (there's a good chance that [this article](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/overriding-mvc-commands) can help) and potentially also the UI.

And yet another alternative: You might be able to achieve the same by using Teams in the organization's site: They behave almost like roles but are only available to a single site (no organization though, but you state that your organizations have sites anyway)

Comment: Thank you @Olaf Kock ,but how could i get the organization-id in the addRole() method

Comment: A role does not have an organization id, not sure what you're trying to achieve: when you create a role, it's just a role. Only when you assign an organization scoped role to someone, there is an organization id involved. But that's far from where you create the role

Comment: Thank you @Oalf Kock for your valuable response,
Yes whatever you said absolutely right ,but we want to store the role-id and **organization-Id** (from which site(organization) the role getting created)in our custom table,even we do not have **request object** so how could I get the organizationId ,is there any possibility to get the organizationId from the **service-context object**

Comment: I don't understand: A role is created from Control Panel, not from within an organization. And even then, it can be *used* in *any* organization. You might get *something* more from a request, but I can't see where this additional information is somewhat relevant in real life.

Comment: yeah the role can be used in any organization but in my case organization roles are specific to that organization , from where you are accesing   
(Ex:I have created one organization with its name "org1" and its having a site ,now I accessed org1 site logged in as test and in the control panel im trying to create the organizationrole so this orgRole automatically should map to org1 organization and this orgRole should not be visible to any of other organizations so thats the reason we are storing organizationId and its roleId in our custom table)